# Is calling disconnect() and close() subsequently the right approach in BLE Android app?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on implementing an Android app that connects to BLE devices but the lack of proper documentation is killing me. Nothing seems to be working the same way twice if I run the app once it might work but the next time stops somewhere(no idea where) but I kinda came to a conclusion that I might have not been using `disconnect()` and `close()` in the right order.

**After let's say an error I call disconnect() first:**

```
 public void disconnect() {
    mScanning = true;
    mConnected = false;
    startedConnect = false;
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        scanLeDevice(true);
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    scanLeDevice(true);
}
```

**then I call close():**

```
public void close() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.close();
    mBluetoothGatt = null;
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing it or wrong? Please be aware that I am calling `scanLeDevice(true);` right after disconnecting but then `close()` is called which I think is just "finishing" everything and stops the scanning right?

Comment: Did you try finding examples on google? I used the search terms "java android bluetooth" and found many.

Comment: @NomadMaker I did but nothing that really works, either too old, lack of explanation moreover that my app is a bit different from what i found.

Comment: Did you add lowenergy to the list of terms?

Comment: @NomadMaker yes of course. I have been researching for weeks about this but maybe because I am new to android. Do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: No. I was giving what I found. Those links contained the docs and examples.

Comment: @NomadMaker one thing, would it make better sense if I call `scanLeDevice(true)` inside `close()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a `BluetoothGatt` object by calling `connectGatt` on a `BluetoothDevice`, you claim one of the 32 (in current Android version) available slots in the Bluetooth stack.

On this object you can now call `connect` and `disconnect` to change the state of the "goal" if Android should try to keep a connection to the device or not. Until you call `disconnect`, Android will (forever) try to connect to the device and automatically reconnect to the device if the connection drops for any reason. Calling `connect` again after `disconnect` will make it try to connect again.

Note: setting `autoConnect` to `false` in the initial `connectGatt` call will set an initial timeout for the first implicit connect attempt (usually 30 seconds), and if the device connects and the connection later drops, it won't automatically try to reconnect.

So the `BluetoothGatt` object can be in the "disconnected" state but still take up one of the 32 slots in the Bluetooth Stack. When you call `close`, you release all the resources for the `BluetoothGatt` object and return the slot to the Bluetooth stack. A close therefore implicitly also means disconnect. To potentially workaround some buggy Android devices, you could call `disconnect` on the `BluetoothGatt` object before `close`. Note that once you have called `close`, you can't call any other methods on that `BluetoothGatt` object.

Note: turning off Bluetooth means destroying all `BluetoothGatt` objects automatically.

Back to your question, I don't really understand what your BLE scanning has to do with 
connect/disconnect/close. Scanning is totally separate from connections and `BluetoothGatt` objects and there are no issues with being connected and performing a scan at the same time. To stop the scan, call `stopScan` on the `BluetoothLeScanner`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have read different things about BLE operations in different forums. Many are saying that I must stop scan before connecting because the scanning interferes with connection but you are saying it doesnt?!

Comment: I dont understand another thing you are saying _"Note that once you have called close, you can't call any other methods on that BluetoothGatt object"_ but how can I re-call scan()? Please check my code and give me an answer if I am doing it correctly there and if not please do an Edit of your answer using my code so that I have it clearer because I am kinda confused.

Comment: No, scan does not interfere with connections. Maybe six years ago or so a few budget phones had some bugs regarding this, but that should be solved a long time ago. What's your issues regarding "how can I re-call scan"? Please show your full code because now you don't show your scan code. Please also show what you have tried. The documentation for BLE scanning can be found at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.

Comment: I just wanna know if doing this whenever I want to disconnect and restart scanning is the right approach: disconnect(), close() then StartScan().

Comment: Calling `disconnect` followed by `close` on a `BluetoothGatt` object, followed by starting a BLE scan is perfectly fine. In your own `disconnect` method, I don't understand why you start the scan there however. To me it makes more sense to start a scan after `close` (even if there's no restrictions when you start the scan).

Comment: yea you are right and sorry I did not change the code in the question but I am actually doing it like that. I removed the startScan from the disconnect() and placed it in another method where I set some flags as well.